# mysql weird behaviour of in/=any operator with subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query:

```
select * from rootTable rt
where
  (select pk
   from someConfigTable
   where col1='someValue') = any(select confRef from t where t.r = rt.r)
and rt.pk = 123
```

`(select pk from someConfigTable where col1='someValue')` returns some number `3456789`
`select confRef from t where t.r = rt.r` returns some collection of numbers `3456789, 3456789`
type of `someConfigTable.pk` an `t.confRef` is `bigint(20)`

But for some reason the query does not return any row!

However, when I replace `(select pk from someConfigTable where col1='someValue')` with constant, it works correctly and returns some rows:

```
select * from rootTable rt
where 3456789 = any(select confRef from t where t.r = rt.r) and rt.pk = 123
```

What is the problem???

`show variables like '%version%'`

```
# Variable_name, Value
innodb_version, 5.6.16
protocol_version, 10
slave_type_conversions, 
version, 5.6.16
version_comment, MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine, x86_64
version_compile_os, Win64
```

Comment: `select pk from someConfigTable where col1='someValue'` is this returning only one value???

Comment: What are the relationships on the tables?

Comment: @DanielB, rootTable is parent and t is child table

Comment: Should work. Recheck your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from rootTable rt
 where (select pk from someConfigTable where col1='someValue') in (select confRef from t          
  where t.r = rt.r) and rt.pk = 123
```

Try this :) But im not 100% sure it will work correctly???

Comment: Unfortunately the same problem with `in` operator.

Comment: is there relation between roottable and someConfig?

Comment: May be you can use join that will be much easier.. :)

Comment: there is not relation between someConfig and rootTable

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare two collections of numbers.  Interesting.  SQL doesn't do a good job of comparing lists to lists.  Try using an explicit `join` instead.  I think this captures the logic:

```
select rt.*
from rootTable rt join
     t
     on t.r = rt.r
where rt.pk = 123 and
      t.confref in (select pk from someConfigTable where col1 = 'someValue');
```

You might need `select distinct` if more than one row from `t` can meet the condition.

Alternatively, your original query might work with an `exists` clause:

```
 where exists (select 1
               from someConfigTable sct join
                    t
                    on sct.pk = t.confReg
               where sct.col1 = 'someValue' and
                     t.r = rt.r
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want one record.

```
select * from rootTable rt
where
  (select pk
   from someConfigTable
   where col1='someValue' LIMIT 1) = any(select confRef from t where t.r = rt.r)
and rt.pk = 123
```

Condition:
1:rootTable should have column -> rootTable column name have to be someConfigTable.pk value

```
select pk
       from someConfigTable
       where col1='someValue' LIMIT 1
```

return a column name. more then one column not accepted because .

it will something like this

```
where Name , Fname =value --wrong!
```

Is that what you want?